# Ubuntu Wifi and drivers problem

Tags: wireless, drivers

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 alongside windows 8 on my Vaio laptop. Wifi is working on windows normally but it's not working on Ubuntu though I can connect to internet through ethernet.There is nothing shown in additional drivers. And `iwconfig` shows the following data

```
eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=16 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
```

`lspci -vnn | grep Network` showed:

```
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0032] (rev 01)
```

I read somewhere that after connecting through ethernet Ubuntu automatically looks for required  wireless drivers but nothing such thing has happened.

<sub>My laptop specification is at: http://www.amazon.in/Sony-Series-SVE1513ACNB-15-5-inch-Laptop/dp/B00D16KEFQ</sub>

Comment: check here http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers

Comment: No help from this when I run the command lspci -nn -d 14e4: Nothing happens

Comment: Run `lspci -vnn | grep Network` and post the result in question you can [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/528795/edit).

Comment: Here is the result of the above command                      01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0032] (rev 01)

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`? if you didn't that, do the commands in terminal and then type "Additional Drivers" in dash then wait for checking drivers and select wireless driver from listed driver, then click "Apply changes" to start installation.

Comment: If you have an interface _wlan0_ then the required driver _ath9k_ is already installed. When you click the Network Manager icon, with the ethernet detached, do you see a list of wireless networks? What happens when you click yours?

Answer (score 0):

Your Ethernet advice is correct, but for it to apply you also need to open your update manager and be sure to click CHECK before clicking "install updates".

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: There is no update manager